# updateUI desaparece los botones de mi JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Verán, estoy haciendo un laberinto, y tengo una clase que extiende de JPanel, y tambien uso graphics, tengo 2 problemas, el primero es que de los dos botones solo de muestra uno, hasta que le paso el mouse por encima, el segundo es que cuando se actualiza mi laberinto ambos botones desaparecen y no aparecen hasta que le paso el mouse por encima, aquí la clase:

```
public final class Grafica extends JPanel {
    
MatrizLab rellenar=new MatrizLab();

JButton btnGenerar = new JButton();
JButton btnBuscar = new JButton();


    public Grafica() {                   
       
        this.setLayout(null); 
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);     
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);  
        DibujarBotones();      
    }

    
   
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {  
           update(g);      
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {              
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image imagen = createImage(800, 600);       
        Graphics2D fondo = (Graphics2D) imagen.getGraphics();       
        Dibujar(fondo);     
        g2.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, this);    
         
    }

    public void Dibujar(Graphics g) {           
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        int x = 140;
        int y = 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                String camino = Integer.toString(j);           
                g2.drawRect(x, y, 26, 26);
                g2.drawString(camino, x + 8, y + 15);
                if (rellenar.getMatriz()[i][j] == 0) {
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.fill3DRect(x, y, 26, 26, true);
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                x = x + 26;
            }
            x = 140;
            y = y + 26;
        }
       
    }   
    
        public void DibujarBotones(){
           
        btnGenerar.setBounds(30, 50, 90, 25);
        btnGenerar.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        btnGenerar.setText("Generar!");
        btnGenerar.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.add(btnGenerar);
        
        ActionListener accion = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {               
                rellenar.RellenaMatriz();
                System.out.println("holi");        
              updateUI();
        
            }
          
        };
        
        btnGenerar.addActionListener(accion);
        
        btnBuscar.setBounds(30, 90, 90, 25);
        btnBuscar.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        btnBuscar.setText("Buscar!");
        btnBuscar.setFocusPainted(false); 
        this.add(btnBuscar); 

        ActionListener accion2 = new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {             
         for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
              System.out.print(rellenar.getMatriz()[i][j]);
           }
            System.out.println();
          }
 
        }
     };
     btnBuscar.addActionListener(accion2);
    }
    
    
    

}
```

Comment: Si, updateUI() es útil pero cuando se trata de Componentes y Layouts, para gráficos, siempre he usado repaint(), por ejemplo en juegos updateUI() tarda o exige mucho cada actualización por segundo, a comparación de rapaint(), Tu problema va con los botones, ¿porque actualizarlos si solo influye en los gráficos?,  crea 2 paneles uno para los botones y otro para los gráficos, y agrégalos con el BorderLayout del frame en sus respectivos lugares

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero luego desde el otro panel no puedo mandar a actualizar el grafico, en el panel de los botones cree un objeto de tipo Grafica, para mandar a actualizar desde el botón pero no actualizaba por lo que me rendí con esa idea,

era tipo 
Grafica actualizar=new Grafica();

luego en el boton ponia
actualizar.updateUI();
pero no sirvió porque no me actualizaba el grafico UnU